# Unblock main thread while waiting for another thread to finish it's work

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

In WinForms application I start worker thread that adds data to root a `XElement`.

Then in main thread I need to wait while worker thread finishes it's work (to get complete `XElement`), and output this XElement to a `textarea`.

If I call `.Join()` on the main thread - it freezes until another thread stops (and user can't click any button on the main form).

**Is it possible to unblock main thread while waiting for another thread to finish it's work??**

I've tried:

**1.**

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
     XmlManager.whReady.WaitOne();
     xDocString = xResultDoc.ToString();
}));
```

**2.**

```
string xDocString = String.Empty;
new Thread(() => { xDocString = XelementToString(); }).Start();

txtXmlTree.Text = xDocString;

public string XelementToString() {
    XmlManager.whReady.WaitOne();
    return xResultDoc.ToString();
}
```

But it had no effect.

EventWaitHandle `XmlManager.whReady.WaitOne();` is being `.Set()` in the worker thread just before it closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use async/await

```
string docString = await Task.Run(() => {
 XmlManager.whReady.WaitOne();
 return xResultDoc.ToString();
}).ConfigureAwait(true);

//Execution flow will resume here once the thread is done.
....
//Now do something here with the text (e.g. display it).
...
```

For example, if you want to run this on a button click, you would have (note the **async** modifier):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  ...The code above goes here...
}
```

As to why your code is not working as expected (both of your attempts):

1. Your code is blocking, because it causes the action to be executed on the thread on which the main form's handle was created (so the UI thread). You typically call BeginInvoke from another (non UI) thread to tell the UI to do something.
2. You start a thread and then immediately expect to have `xDocString` ready to use. It doesn't work that way. By the time this line is executed `txtXmlTree.Text = xDocString;` the thread may or may not have finished executing (most likely not finished).

I hope now you see why `await` is a way better option. You don't have to synchronize your workers with the main thread, you don't have worry about context switching and making sure UI code executes on the UI thread.

Comment: Can you please implement the same but without using `async/await`? Because I'm pretty new to multithreading and I haven't learned `async/await` yet :(

Comment: @jamesbong: It's too much code to write without async/await. Actually it would take me more to write it than you to understand this. Nothing to lose.

Comment: Maybe I exaggerated a bit, not that too much code. But you should still learn about async and await.

Comment: does your code do the same as mine (#1) where I call `BeginInvoke` ?

Comment: @jamesbong Why don't you try? Just a few lines of code to copy&paste.

Comment: @jamesbong: No, not really. Your code is blocking, because it causes the action to be executed on the thread on which the main form's handle was created (so the UI thread). You typically call `BeginInvoke` from **another** (non UI) thread to tell the UI to do something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) class since it's a WinForm application.

The BackgroundWorker will let the sub-task to be run in the background, and notify the main form on it's completion (as well as progress, if needed), so the main form will be able to display the output in the text area once the sub-task is complete.

Comment: too late to rewrite the whole application :)

Comment: No need to rewrite anything. It's as simple as dropping a BackgroundWorker to your form and attaching to it's `DoWork` and `RunWorkerFinished` events. Read the linked MSDN page, it has some pretty complete examples.